# How to append data to wp_post and wp_postmeta tables in wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am building a site that has a list of stores.

How can I add my store info to `wp_post` and `wp_postmeta` so I don't have to manually add them in dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You don't to modify the posts in database for that. You can simply add your desired modification at the end of post content every time a post is being displayed.

```
function my_function($content) {    
    $content .= 'My Store Info';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
```

Comment: thank you! however i do have lots of stores to post and for each i have to modify a couple pieces of info. Are you suggesting the best way is to auto modify post info? can I balk post for a large amount of stores the same time?

Comment: Also, I've noticed wp_posts and wp_postmeta don't capture any info related to images. is there a way to auto upload images?